# Efficiently parsing email body in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to parse multiple email bodies that look like:

```
Name: Bob smith
Email: hellol@aol.com
Phone Number: 4243331212
```

As part of a larger program I have the following function to parse the page:

```
function parseBody(i, body) {

result = []
result[0] = i

var name = body.match(new RegExp(/\*Name:\*(.*) /))
if (name) { 
     result[1] = name[1]
}

......

   return result;

}
```

rather than have potentially 10 fields to parse and load into the result array by if statements , is there a more efficient way using JavaScript to parse this page and load the array?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "10 fields"? The example you gave has only 3.

Comment: Just split into lines and take the part after the colon on every one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to find a way to split the body and identify the keys and values to build a result object.

- In order to split the body, you can use a regular expression to match the structure of a key:

  ```
  let delimiter = new RegExp('(\w*): ')
  ```
- Then use the split method on the body with this regexp to get an array with an alternance of keys and values :

  ```
  let split = body.split(delimiter)
  ```
- Finally sort the keys from the values with a loop :

  ```
  let res = {}
  for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i += 2)
    res[ split[i] ] = split[ i+1 ]  // even indexes are key, odd ones are values
  ```

Pushing forward you can remove empty keys and trailing spaces and carriage return with a more advanced regexp. Here is a possible implementation :

```
    function parseBody (body) {
      let split = body
        .split(new RegExp('(\w*): ([^\t\r\n]*)[\t\r\n]*')) // removes trailing line feed
        .filter(x=>x) // remove empty matches
      let res = {}
      for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i += 2)
        res[ split[i] ] = split[ i+1 ] // even indexes are key, odd ones are values
      return res
    }
```

*This returns an associative array but you have the idea if you want a simple array.*

Comment: Thanks, a very interesting idea . I am getting an error : "Missing ; before statement." in The "let split = body" line

Comment: I'm not getting any error, what interpreter or linter are you using ?

Comment: You tagged your question as JavaScript, google script app doesn't support ES6 syntax. You script will work if you replace the "let" by "var" and "x=>x" by "function (x) { return x }"

Answer (score 3):

handles numbers and undefined

```js
var mailBody = `
Name: Bob smith
Email: hellol@aol.com
Phone Number: 4243331212
key4:value4
key5:value 5
key6:
  key7: value7
`;

var obj = {}; 
mailBody.split('\n').forEach(v=>v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, (s,key,val)=>{
  obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val);
}));

console.log( obj );
```