# JS syntax error while building object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[image]

I need to parse multiple email bodies that look like:

```
Name: Bob smith
Email: hellol@aol.com
Phone Number: 4243331212
```

As part of a larger program I have the following function to parse the page based on [Efficiently parsing email body in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897002/efficiently-parsing-email-body-in-javascript/45897479#45897479):

```
function parse (i, body) {
 var obj = {}; 
 body.split('\n').forEach(v=>v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, (s,key,val)=>{obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val);}));

 var objArr = Object.values(obj);

 var res = [];
 res[0] = i
 res.push(objArr)

 return res
```

}

when I run this I get a syntax error in:

```
 body.split('\n').forEach(v=>v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, (s,key,val)=>{obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val);}));
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the exact error? Also, you haven't done yourself any favors by sticking everything on one line. Line numbers would have be able to help you narrow it down. I'm going to guess it's a misplaced brace problem.

Comment: In the apps script editor it just says "Syntax error. (line 43, file "Code") (that line). I ran the code in jslint and the output said "Wrap the parameter in parens."

Comment: Trying splitting it over a few lines so you can get a better location. Also, running this is a debugger would probably work as well.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `parse(0, "Name: Bob smith\nEmail: hellol@aol.com\nPhone Number: 4243331212")` gives back an array of `"0,Bob smith,hellol@aol.com,4243331212"`. Not sure what that prefixed "0" is, but I didn't get any errors. Tested in the Edge console.

Comment: yes that's what it should so. The code from the previous question did work. I'm trying to run it as apps script and that's where the problem occurs. I've added a screenshot. The error is occuring on line 44

Comment: I'm going to guess the Javascript engine it uses doesn't support regex literals like that. Can't you use a string regex pattern?

Comment: In another section of my code I have" var name = messagebody.match(new RegExp(/\*Name:\*(.*) /));" - this is working so I think it probably does work. What do you mean by a "string regex pattern" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script is based on the ECMA Script version that doesn't support arrow functions. Replace

```
array.forEach(element => element.replace(expression))
```

with

```
array.forEach(function(element) {

return element.replace(expression);

});
```

Comment: I;ve changed it to :   body.split('\n').forEach(function(v) { return v.replace(/\s*(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)\s*/, (s,key,val)=>{obj[key]=isNaN(val)||val.length<1?val||undefined:Number(val);})}) - However I'm still getting a syntax error. does ' (s,key,val)=>...' also need to be replaced?

Comment: Everything with => in it must be replaced with proper functions (with parameters and return statement). For example function (a, b, c) { return a + b + c; }